# update query value in foreach statement with looping textbox values PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my database inside the foreach statement but it gives me the same values that I insert on to the last value that I input.

Let's say I have a looping textbox at the previous page.

```
    $i = 0;
    while($row_recordset = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) 

            {           
        echo "<tr>";
        <td'><input type='text' name='atten_ave".$i."''></td>
        echo "</tr>";

  $i++;
}
```

Now this code will get each value of the textbox and should be update the database from the previous page.

```
foreach($_POST as $textbox => $values) {

            $sessionbatch = getbatchno('BATCHNO');

            $query_update = "UPDATE `grades` 
                            SET 
                            `ATTEN_SUM` = '$values'

                            WHERE
                            `BATCHNO` = '$sessionbatch'
                             ";

            if(mysql_query($query_update)){
                echo 'SUCCESS';
                } else{
                        die(mysql_error());
                          }
```

when I check my ATTEN_SUM COLUMN the values are the SAME base on the last input on the textbox.

Comment: Please fix your code in the first block

Comment: hi, what do you mean sir? I didn't put all the codes because i just only want to show the loop of the textbox and assigning of different names every textbox. thanks for the reply.

Comment: The syntax in the line where you echo the table cell is maddening lol.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

First off, *do not* loop through every value in `$_POST`. Give your textboxes an idenitcal name that has `[]` appended to it, like `name="atten_ave[]"`. This will create an array for them within `$_POST`, then you can loop through them all safely with:

```
foreach($_POST["atten_ave"] as $textbox => $values) { ....
```

Now whenever `getbatchno('BATCHNO');` returns a value it has already returned within the life of that loop, it will overwrite the update it previously did with that similar value. So if it is returning the same value in every iteration, your query will just keep overwriting itself.